# About node.js return data to ajax call function

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

> Now I have a question like this:
>   I created a server with node.js ,and the server have receive a ajax request.With the data received from ajax ,node.js send a post request to another server. Now I have got the data from another server and the main question is how to send the data back to ajax, I have tried many ways but it does not work.

Can somebody help me on this issue?

> here is my code

====ajax request

```
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'http://localhost:8888',   //  这里要改成服务器的地址
         data: userData,
         success: function (data) {
             console.log(data);
         }
     })
```

====

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url == '/') {
        var data = '';
        var imdata;
        util.log(util.inspect(req));
        util.log('Request recieved: \nmethod: ' + req.method + '\nurl: ' + req.url);
        req.on('data', function (chunk) {
            imdata = querystring.parse(data += chunk);//转成对象的格式
        })
        req.on('end', function () {
            var myIm = new ServerApi('e782429e48cb99f44b9c5effe414ac72', 'b88b9f2a2f74');
            myIm.createUserId(imdata, function (err, data) {
//createUesrId is a api to deal with post request 
                console.log(data);//the data have received from another server,and now i do not know how  to return the data to ajax success function

            })
        })
```

====the api to create user id with post requeset

```
ServerApi.prototype.postDataHttps = function (url, data, callback) {
    this.checkSumBuilder();

    var urlObj = urlParser.parse(url);
    var httpHeader = {
        'AppKey': this.AppKey,
        'Nonce': this.Nonce,
        'CurTime': this.CurTime,
        'CheckSum': this.CheckSum,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
    };
    var options = {
        hostname: urlObj.hostname,
        port: 80,
        path: urlObj.path,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: httpHeader
    };
    var that = this;
    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {

        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
        console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            if (Object.prototype.toString.call(callback) === '[object Function]') {
                var result = JSON.parse(chunk);

                callback.call(that, null, result);
                return result;
            }
        });
    });

    var postData = querystring.stringify(data);
    req.write(postData);
    req.end(data);

    req.on('error', function (err) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(callback) === '[object Function]') {
            callback.call(that, err, null);
        }
    });

}
ServerApi.prototype.createUserId = function (data, callback) {
    var url = 'https://api.netease.im/nimserver/user/create.action';
    var postData = {
        'accid': data['accid'] || '',
        'name': data['name'] || '',
        'props': data['props'] || '',
        'icon': data['icon'] || '',
        'token': data['token'] || ''
    };
    this.postDataHttps(url, postData, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your server code. The one with `http.createServer(function (req, res) {...}`

Notice how you got a `req` and `res` parameter?

So on event `end`, that is `req.on('end' function...` Right after the line where you got a comment saying the 'data is received from another server', you can do something like;

```
res.writeHead(/*HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FOR_AJAX_CLIENT=*/200);
res.end('Done');
```

to send a response back to your client with HTTP response code = 200 and the message in the HTTP body would be 'Done'. Note that, there are quite a number of things you can do with the response object, you may want to see the documentation for more information.

**See:**
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_statusmessage_headers

OR
(中文版)

http://nodeapi.ucdok.com/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse_7847

Quick explanation in Chinese：
在服务器的代码`req.on('end'...`那里， 你可以用`res`object打回给你的AJax client.